# Proving a set is a manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, submanifold, implicit-function

> Prove that the following set is a manifold and find it's dimension $$M=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R^3}\times\Bbb{R^3}|x\cdot y=0, \|x\|=\|y\|=1\}$$

So $M$ can be thought of as the intersection of the following equations: $$x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3=0$$ $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$$$$y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2=1$$

I tried defining an implicit function $F(x,y)$ s.t $F(x,y)=0$ iff $(x,y)\in M$ but didn't know how to take it from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What if you consider the $\mathcal C^1$ function $\mathbf F : \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R^3$ defined as: $$\mathbf F(\mathbf x)= \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3 \\
    x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 -1 \\
    y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2-1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} $$

Can you check $\text{rank}(D \mathbf F(\mathbf x))$ now?

Comment: I guess the rank is 3 as long as $\vec x\neq 0$ and $\vec y\neq 0$?

Comment: @GalBenAyun Are you even interested in the case where the vectors are $\mathbf 0$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove it's a manifold so I guess I can take a small enough environment $W$ s.t $x=0$ and $y=0$ aren't in the intersection $M\cap W$

Comment: If the rank of the jacobian is 3 then by the implicit function theorem $M= \mathbf F^{-1}(  \mathbf 0 )$ is an $(6-3)$-dimentional manifold. You're done.